# Não consigo colocar uma subquery dentro do IN no PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Abaixo está o codigo para criação da tabela e inserção de alguns dados para teste.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_empresas]( [data] [date] NULL, [nome] [varchar](100) NULL, [valor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-01-01',103), 'EMPRESA1', 100)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-02-02',103), 'EMPRESA2', 200)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-03-03',103), 'EMPRESA3', 300)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-04-04',103), 'EMPRESA4', 400)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-05-05',103), 'EMPRESA5', 500)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-06-06',103), 'EMPRESA6', 600)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-07-07',103), 'EMPRESA7', 700)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-08-08',103), 'EMPRESA8', 800)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-09-09',103), 'EMPRESA9', 900)

INSERT INTO tb_empresas (data, nome, valor)
VALUES (convert(datetime,'2012-10-10',103), 'EMPRESA10', 1000)
```

O `PIVOT` funcionando está assim:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATA) AS MES, NOME, VALOR FROM tb_empresas)
AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS 
PIVOT
    ( 
        MAX(VALOR) 
        FOR NOME 
        IN([EMPRESA1],[EMPRESA2],[EMPRESA3])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Porém aonde está EMPRESA1, EMPRESA2 e EMPRESA3, precisaria trazer em um select todos os nomes da empresa por exemplo:

```
IN(SELECT nome FROM tb_empresas)
```

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link para ver se te ajuda: http://www.devmedia.com.br/pivot-no-sql-server-invertendo-linhas-e-colunas-em-um-exemplo-real/28318

Answer (score 3):

Eu sabia que tinha visto algo, só nao lembrava onde.
[Na DevMedia tem o mesmo exemplo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-os-operadores-pivot-e-unpivot-no-sql-server/27339):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OBTER_COLUNAS_DINAMICAMENTE] 
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    DECLARE @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @COLUNAS = '' 
SELECT @COLUNAS = COALESCE(@COLUNAS + '[' + (CAST(NOME AS NVARCHAR(255))) + '],','') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NOME FROM tb_empresas) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS 

SET @COLUNAS = LEFT (@COLUNAS, LEN(@COLUNAS)-1) 

DECLARE @SQLSTRING NVARCHAR(500); 
SET @SQLSTRING = N' SELECT * FROM (SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATA) AS MES, NOME, VALOR FROM tb_empresas) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS 
PIVOT( MAX(VALOR) FOR NOME IN('+@COLUNAS+')) AS PivotTable;' 

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING
```

Pode utilizar esta procedure para listar todas as empresas e fazer o pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação da [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) somente são permitidas colunas. Não será possível colocar ai uma seleção dinâmica.

```
FOR

[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]

IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],

   ... [last pivoted column])

) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```