# Pivot colunas dinâmicas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso exibir isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguindo as instruções dos link´s:

[Utilizar o operador PIVOT sem agregação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22074/utilizar-o-operador-pivot-sem-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

[Não consigo colocar uma subquery dentro do IN no PIVOT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8731/n%C3%A3o-consigo-colocar-uma-subquery-dentro-do-in-no-pivot)

[Pivot dinâmico com SQL Server](http://vladimirrech.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/pivot-dinamico-com-sql-server.html)

Cheguei a este script:

```
create table #temp  (
ano int not null,
item int not null,
valor int
)

insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2014,1,4400)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2015,1,4500)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2016,1,4600)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2017,1,4700)

insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2014,2,10600)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2015,2,10900)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2016,2,11000)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2017,2,11300)

insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2014,5,12000)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2015,5,13000)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2016,5,14000)
insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2017,5,15000)

declare @cols nvarchar(max)
set @cols = stuff((
  select distinct ',' 
    + quotename(ano) 
  from #temp
  for xml path('')
), 1,1, '');

print @cols

declare @query as nvarchar(max)

set @query='SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT item
            , ano
            , valor
        FROM #temp
    ) AS t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(valor)
        FOR ano IN ( ' + @cols + ' ) 
    ) as P;';

print @query

execute(@query)

drop table #temp
```

O caminho é este mesmo ou teria uma forma melhor de abordar esta questão?

Comment: Você precisa criar as tabelas temporárias mesmo ou já possuem elas no banco de dados? Também, tem alguma razão específica porque está usando o `execute` invés de montar uma query diretamente no sql server?

Comment: @rodrigogq Só postei o exemplo com tabelas temporárias para facilitar a execução e o entendimento.  As tabelas vão estar no bd. Seriam várias tabelas e todas com esta característica, dados por ano que deveriam ser exibidos em forma de planilha. Pela quantidade de dados e combinações preciso de uma solução onde consigo as colunas de forma dinâmica. Uso o `execute` justamente para concatenar as colunas dinamicamente. Pesquisei bastante e não achei outra solução. Só queria ter certeza que estou no caminho certo, pois como já disse esta solução vai ser aplicada em várias ocasiões na aplicação.

Comment: entendi. Neste caso não vejo nenhum problema na sua construção. Lembre-se que se você desejar a operação inversa também pode usar o `UNPIVOT`.. Isso também é uma operação bem comum a pedido de clientes.

Comment: @rodrigogq São vários históricos com vários indicadores por ano. Preciso exibi-lo que forma que possam ser analisados e a melhor forma e planilhar. É fundamental utilizar uma abordagem dinâmica. Achei o uso do `execute` meio "gambiarra", ou uma solução a maneira de Thor, na martelada. kkk Contudo não vi nenhuma outra abordagem nas pesquisas que fiz. O post é para garantir que não estou complicando e poderia ter um solução mais simples e elegante.

Comment: Esta tortura só existe se não souber os anos. Se souber o código é super simples. A resposta para sua pergunta é não, não se pode definir as colunas da tabela pivotada dinamicamente.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Pivot T-SQL Dinâmico Sequencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289481/pivot-t-sql-din%c3%a2mico-sequencial)

Answer (score 0):

Realmente não é possível no SQL Server criar um PIVOT com colunas dinâmicas. O SGBD precisa que as colunas estejam definidas para que consiga fazer o transporte das linhas para colunas.

A única solução seria realmente gerar essa query do PIVOT em string, seja através de uma programação que já envia a query pronta para o SQL Server (C#, Python, PHP etc.) ou dentro do próprio SQL Server criando uma Procedure ou Script.

Documentação oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  
    Item:       Script para facilitar a geração de pivot dinâmivo
    Criado por: Renato Cunha - renato.a.t.cunha@outlook.com
    Data:       28-06-2022
*/

SET NOCOUNT ON  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON   
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON


    create table #temp  (
    ano int not null,
    item int not null,
    valor int
    )

    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2014,1,4400)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2015,1,4500)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2016,1,4600)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2017,1,4700)

    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2014,2,10600)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2015,2,10900)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2016,2,11000)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2017,2,11300)

    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2014,5,12000)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2015,5,13000)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2016,5,14000)
    insert into #temp (ano,item, valor) values (2017,5,15000)

declare @tabela varchar(100) = '#temp' -- nome da tabela
declare @coluna1 varchar(100) = 'item' -- primeira coluna do select
declare @colunaArray varchar(100) = 'ano' -- coluna base do pivot
declare @colunaValor varchar(100) = 'valor' -- coluna com os valores
--------------------------------------------------------------------

declare @arrayCol varchar(max) = ''  -- array dinâmico do pivot
declare @arrayColName varchar(max) = ''  -- array dinâmico com os nomes das colunas
declare @coluna varchar(100) -- nome da coluna retornado no cursor
declare @contador int = 0 -- contador dinâmico para arrray  
declare @query varchar(max) = 'select ' + @coluna1 -- variavel da query final

-- cursor contendo os meses distintos e ordenados
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
select distinct ano from #temp order by 1 
-- abre
OPEN cursor1
    -- pega o primeiro mes e alimenta a variável
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @coluna
    -- atribui o primeiro registro ao contador
    set @contador = @contador + 1   
    
    -- percorre enquanto houver
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        -- se for o primeiro, escreve o array de meses sem a primeira virgula
        if (@contador = 1) begin                
            set @arrayCol = @arrayCol + '[' + @coluna + ']' -- array q será usado no pivot
            set @arrayColName = @arrayColName + ',isnull([' + @coluna + '],0) as [col_' + @coluna + ']' -- array do campos (com os nomes das colunas)
        end
        else begin
            set @arrayCol = @arrayCol + ',[' + @coluna + ']' -- array q será usado no pivot
            set @arrayColName = @arrayColName + ', isnull([' + @coluna + '],0) as [col_' + @coluna + ']' -- array do campos (com os nomes das colunas)
        end
        -- pega o próximo do cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @coluna
        -- atualiza o contador
        set @contador = @contador + 1       
    END -- final do cursor
    
    -- mota a query do pivot
    set @query = @query + @arrayColName + ' from ' + @tabela + ' pivot (sum(' + @colunaValor + ') for ' + @colunaArray + ' in (' + @arrayCol + ')) p'           

CLOSE cursor1 -- fecha
DEALLOCATE cursor1 -- limpa da me´mória

-- executa a query
exec(@query)
```

Comment: Essa resposta parece muito semelhante à outra que tu postou. Se há diferenças, apague essa resposta e edite a outra com as correções/alterações.

Answer (score -3):

Uma possível solução seria, ao invés de transformar em colunas, o resultado das colunas que contem o ano XML, e então trabalhar dentro da sua aplicação:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT item
        , ano
        , valor
    FROM #temp
) AS t
PIVOT XML(
    MAX(valor)
    FOR ano IN (any) 
) as P;
```

Referência: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: Resposta deveria ser para sql server e não Oracle