# Pivot T-SQL Dinâmico Sequencial

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Quebrando a cabeça aqui pra criar uma proc usando pivot para essa transformação:

[image: a busy cat]

Existe a possibilidade?

*Utilizando sql server 2008R2

EDIT:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Teste5
    (name VARCHAR(50),message VARCHAR(50),dtStart VARCHAR(50))
    GO
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 1','Observ','2018-04-06')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 2','Observ','2018-04-06')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 1','Observ','2018-04-05')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 3','Observ','2018-04-02')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 4','Observ','2018-03-09')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 2','Observ','2018-03-09')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 1','Observ','2018-03-02')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 1','Observ','2018-01-05')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 4','Observ','2017-10-30')
    INSERT INTO #Teste5 VALUES('Curso 2','Observ','2017-09-25')
    GO
    select * from #Teste5

    DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    --Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
    SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
    + QUOTENAME(dtStart)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dtStart FROM #Teste5) AS dtStart

    --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
      N'SELECT name, ' + @ColumnName + '
        FROM #Teste5
        PIVOT(MAX(message) 
      FOR dtStart IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
    --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

A minha tabela já existe. O create table é só para demonstrar melhor

Comment: Poste o código que está trabalhando, a estrutura da base e o que deseja saber realmente, por favor.

Comment: Recomendo que dê uma olhada antes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Acredito que não seja a melhor forma, mas resolvi criando uma tabela temporaria com os dados da tabela curso adicionando uma coluna com um número gerado sequencialmente i++ utilizando a seguinte expressão: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY curso ORDER BY curso  ASC) AS Row#. Após criar essa tabela usei o índice gerado para definir as colunas no pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que não seja a melhor forma, mas resolvi criando uma tabela temporária com os dados da tabela curso adicionando uma coluna com um número gerado sequencialmente i++ utilizando a seguinte expressão:

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY curso ORDER BY curso ASC) AS Row#.
```

Após criar essa tabela usei o índice gerado para definir as colunas no pivot

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(Row#) FROM (select distinct Row# from #TableTemp) AS Row#

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'SELECT name, ' + @ColumnName 
+ ' FROM #TableTempPIVOT(MAX(dtStart) FOR row# IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```